# Add Vertical Scroll in IE9

Tags: 2013, master-page, css, custom-masterpage

I'm re-branding an Intranet publishing site for SharePoint 2013 using VS2012 - I'm creating project as a Feature and deploying the .wsp file locally.

Using IE9, short pages have no vertical scroll bar out of the box. This is causing a horizontal page jump when navigating between pages with vertical scroll bar and those without. I tried fixing it with variations of the following:

```
html
{
    height: 101%;
}
```

When I try the following, I get double vertical scroll bars on long pages:

```
html
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

My custom style sheet is correctly being applied last. However, I cannot understand why setting height to 101% is not inserting the vertical scroll bar.

**UPDATE 12/09/13**

I have even tried inlining the CSS height and this doesn't work wither:

```
<body style="height: 101%;">
    ...
</body>
```

However, I finally got scroll bar to render by inlining CSS as follows:

```
<div id="s4-bodyContainer" style="height:101%;">
```

Note Whitelaw's answer for explanation.

Comment: Do any of your HTML elements (i.e. the BODY) have a scroll="no" attribute?

Comment: No John, none that I can find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SharePoint, the main viewport of the webpage is not the `html` or `body` elements. Instead, they use `div#s4-workspace`, which is meant to take up 100% of the height and width (minus the ribbon).

Try adding your overflow-y to this element:

```
#s4-workspace {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: This should work, but you can also just use #s4-workspace as the selector. The div portion of the selector is unnecessary.

Comment: Thx, that worked! I was under the impression that I couldn't target #s4-ribbonrow, #s4-workspace, #s4-titlerow, #s4-bodyContainer directly because they were dynamically adjusted on page load?