# Moving Scroll Bar to Top not working in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, web-part, javascript, master-page

We are using below code on our web application master pages inside SharePoint 2003 to make scroll bar position always on top.

```
function MoveUp() {
            if (window.parent.document.getElementById('WSSMainContainer') != null)
                window.parent.document.getElementById('WSSMainContainer').focus();

            if (window.parent.document.getElementById('MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ2') != null) 
            {
                window.parent.document.getElementById('MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ2').scrolling = 'no';
                window.parent.document.getElementById('MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ2').style.overflow = 'hidden';

                if (window.document.body.scrollHeight > 1400)
                    window.parent.document.getElementById('MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ2').style.height = window.document.body.scrollHeight + 100;
            }
        }
<body onload="MoveUp();"> ....
```

Now we migrated our application to SharePoint 2013 and the same code we are using is no longer working.

Anyone experience the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 and 2013 scroll within a div called `s4-workspace` not within the parent window. Based on looking at your script coming from 2003, I think this might need a major re-work...

Here are some examples of other questions that have dealt with scrolling issues that have a lot of good background on how scrolling works in modern installations (since it's non-standard... thanks Microsoft!):

- [Add Vertical Scroll in IE9](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84565/add-vertical-scroll-in-ie9)
- [Can't get jquery to work](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113619/cant-get-jquery-to-work)
- [Scroll position in Sharepoint 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26539/scroll-position-in-sharepoint-2010)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870533/partial-rendering-for-sharepoint-application-pages

Of particular note, in the [3rd link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26539/scroll-position-in-sharepoint-2010) you'll see this line, that might help with what you're trying to accomplish:

```
document.getElementById("s4-workspace").scrollTop
```

You should be able to set that to 0 in order to make sure you're at the top of the page, but I'm less sure what you'll need to modify to recreate the inner-webpart behavior from the original.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a simple jQuery to this works like a charm in SharePoint !!

```
$("#s4-workspace").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
```

Late answer though !!